# Why this SQL DELETE query using INNER JOIN is not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete, rdbms

I am trying to perform this SQL DELETE query that involves some **INNER JOIN**. I want delete only from the main table named **Market_Commodity_Price_Series**. I am using **MySql**.

This is my query:

```
DELETE
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series AS MCPS
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MDCD
      ON MCPS.market_commodity_details_id = MDCD.id
INNER JOIN MarketDetails AS MD
      ON MDCD.market_details_id = MD.id
WHERE MD.market_name = "Kimironko"
```

The problem is that performing this query I obtain the following error message:

> #42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'MCPS INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MDCD       ON
>   MCPS.market_co' at line 2

The "strange" thing is that the SELECT * version of this query works fine, I obtain the records that I expect.

I want to use the delete version to delete these records only from the main query specified by the **FROM** clause.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify from which table you want the record to be deleted: 
(Note the table alias after `DELETE`)

```
DELETE MCPS
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series AS MCPS
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MDCD
      ON MCPS.market_commodity_details_id = MDCD.id
INNER JOIN MarketDetails AS MD
      ON MDCD.market_details_id = MD.id
WHERE MD.market_name = "Kimironko"
```